# Google Map API is not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am on my exam project, trying to get Google Map API to show my current location. But it's not working, and just showing a blank/grey page instead of a map.

I tried searching in here, and found a couple of responses about the width and height, but nothing seems to work for me.

Here is error:

[image: Error picture]

I am only allowed to code in this project with HTML, CSS AND JavaScript.

Here is my code

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY KEY IS HERE AND WORKING"></script>
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="kort">
      <button type="button" onclick="visPosition();">Vis min bils position</button>
  </div>
```

My CSS:

```
    #kort {
  width: 100%;
  height: 755px;
}
```

My JS:

```
    function visPosition() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(visKort, visFejl);
    } else {
        alert("Din browser understøtter ikke dette element");
    }
}

// Definerer funktionen når den bliver kaldt succesfuldt.
function visKort(position) {
    // Får lokations dataen
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    long = position.coords.longitude;
    let latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

    let mineIndstillinger = {
        center: latlong,
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    }

    let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("kort"), mineIndstillinger);
    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position:latlong, map:map, title:"Du er her" });
}

// Definerer fejlene der kan opstå når funktionen bliver kaldt.
function visFejl(error) {
    if(error.code == 1) {
        result.innerHTML = "Du vil ikke dele din position.";
    } else if(error.code == 2) {
        result.innerHTML = "Netværket er nede.";
    } else if(error.code == 3) {
        result.innerHTML = "Timed out.";
    } else {
        result.innerHTML = "Ukendt Fejl.";
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to coding.

Comment: Looking this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34659978/10971575

Comment: If this is the real markup/script then you should have a look at how a html document is structured and where to put what.

Comment: @BhavikKalariya What has the "zoom level" to do with this question? And where did you find jQuery?

Comment: The code is not even showing the map, let alone the gray areas.

Comment: Have a look to see if there are any errors in your JS console.